# How to match pairs of values contained in two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates, numpy-ndarray

I have two sets of coordinates and want to find out which coordinates of the `coo` set are identical to any coordinate in the `targets` set. I want to know the indices in the `coo` set which means I'd like to get a list of indices or of bools.

```
import numpy as np

coo = np.array([[1,2],[1,6],[5,3],[3,6]]) # coordinates
targets = np.array([[5,3],[1,6]]) # coordinates of targets

print(np.isin(coo,targets))

[[ True False]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]]
```

The desired result would be one of the following two:

```
[False True True False] # bool list
[1,2] # list of concerning indices
```

My problem is, that ...

- `np.isin` has no `axis`-attribute so that I could use `axis=1`.
- even applying *logical and* to each row of the output would return `True` for the last element, which is wrong.

I am aware of loops and conditions but I am sure Python is equipped with ways for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This solution will scale worse for *large arrays*, for such cases the other proposed answers will perform better.

---

Here's one way taking advantage of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
(coo[:,None] == targets).all(2).any(1)
# array([False,  True,  True, False])
```

---

**Details**

Check for every row in `coo` whether or not it matches another in `target` by direct comparisson having added a first axis to `coo` so it becomes broadcastable against `targets`:

```
(coo[:,None] == targets)

array([[[False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [False,  True]]])
```

Then check which `ndarrays` along the second axis have [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) values to `True`:

```
(coo[:,None] == targets).all(2)

array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False]])
```

And finally use [`any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) to check which rows have at least one `True`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple and intuitive solution that actually uses `numpy.isin()`, to **match tuples**, rather than match individual numbers:

```
# View as a 1d array of tuples
coo_view     = coo.view(dtype='i,i').reshape((-1,))
targets_view = targets.view(dtype='i,i').reshape((-1,))

result = np.isin(coo_view, targets_view)
print (result)
print(result.nonzero()[0])
```

**Output:**

```
[False  True  True False]
[1 2]
```

**Notes:**

1. The creation of these [views](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) does not involve any copying of data.
2. The `dtype='i,i'` specifies that we want each element of the view to be a tuple of two integers

Comment: The view creates an array of tuples were the second element of the tuple is always 0, and the original array was kind of "flattened". For example, `A = np.array([
    [3, 1], 
    [4, 1], 
    [1, 4]
]).view(dtype='i,i').reshape((-1,))` returns `array([(3, 0), (1, 0), (4, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (4, 0)],`

Comment: Describing this as **tuples** is misleading.  You made a structured array.  Records are displayed as tuples, as opposed to lists, but they aren't actually tuples.

Answer (score 2):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP/blob/master/numpy_indexed/arraysetops.py#L86) package implements functionality of this type in a vectorized manner (disclaimer: I am its author). Sadly numpy lacks a lot of this functionality out of the box; I started numpy_indexed with the intention of having it merged into numpy, but there are some backwards compatibility concerns, and big packages like that tend to move slowly. So that hasnt happened in the last 3 years; but the python packaging ecosystem works so well nowadays that just adding one more package to your environment is just as simple, really.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
bools = npi.in_(targets, coo)
```

This will have a time-complexity similar to that of the solution posted by @fountainhead (logarithmic rather than linear, as per the currently accepted answer), but also the npi library will give you the safety of automated tests, and a lot of other convenient options, should you decide to approach the problem from a slightly different angle.

Comment: I'm not sure about the currently accepted answer having a linear time-complexity. When we start with two arrays of size `2m` numbers and `2n` numbers respectively, the broadcasted size will be `2mn`. So, the `==` comparison of the broadcasted arrays will always perform `2mn` numeric comparison. It will be **always** `2mn` comparisons, and **not just in the worst case**. (The worst case is when there are zero matches). In contrast, `isin`-based solutions stop further matches when each successful match occurs.

Comment: It's linear in both n and m; so quadratic if you scale both at the same time. That is indeed as brute-force as it gets, and smarter solutions can have a huge advantage in practice

Comment: shouldn't it be the other way around? npi.in_(coo, targets)? I tried your class and it only worked this way and the documentation also says so. Cheers.