# Python Numpy - if array is in array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I want to check with most efficiency way (the fastest way), if some array (or list) is in numpy array.
But when I do this:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array(
    [
        [[1, 2]],
        [[3, 4]]
    ])

print([[3, 5]] in a)
```

It only compares the first value and returns `True`

Somebody knows, how can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over Numpy matrix rows to apply a function each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468717/iterating-over-numpy-matrix-rows-to-apply-a-function-each)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me, too.

Comment: for your original data, is only the matrix `a` large or the query matrix is also large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be a duplicate of:
[How to match pairs of values contained in two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54828039/how-to-match-pairs-of-values-contained-in-two-numpy-arrays)

In any case, something like the first answer should do it if I understand correctly:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array(
    [
        [[1, 2]],
        [[3, 4]]
    ])

b = numpy.array([[3,5]])

print((b[:,None] == a).all(2).any(1))
```

Which outputs:

```
array([False,  True])
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, it is faster than solution from joostblack, but it still takes a long time on my big data series. Is there any other faster solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add `tolist()` in your last line:

```
print([[3, 5]] in a.tolist())
```

gives

```
False
```

Comment: I do not know what your application is but I think you can drop the double brackets and instead use single brackets.

Comment: This works! Thank you, but it is really slow. I have big data series and with them it takes more than 1 minute. Is there any faster solution?