# View numpy array of pairs as tuples

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of pairs of size (N,2), and I want to convert them to tuples to be able to perform an `isin` operation.

I tried using `view`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
coo = np.array([[1,2],[1,6],[5,3],[3,6]]) # coordinates
coo.view(dtype='i,i').reshape((-1))
>>> (array([(1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 0), (6, 0), (5, 0), (3, 0), (3, 0), (6, 0)],
       dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')]),)
```

The solution should be something like:

```
[(1,2), (1,6), (5,3), (3,6)]
```

But it appears that `view` instead of creating tuples with the two elements it justs adds a zero to the second element of the tuple.

I know I can use a map, but I'd like to use something like view so the operation is faster, as the original array takes a couple of mb.

Comment: Btw, I made this question because [how to match pairs of values contained in two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54828039/how-to-match-pairs-of-values-contained-in-two-numpy-arrays) did not work

Comment: No, it doesn't answer it because it doesn't use view and it duplicates the data. But it might be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Are you sure you need an array of tuples?  Such an array has to be object dtype, a bastardized list! It can't be a `view`

Comment: That 'tuples' answer is not genuine tuples.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54850510/901925.  It makes a structured array - pay attention to the dtype.  It may work in your case, but you need to use the correct terminology, unless you like the duplicates link.

Comment: `np.unique` with axis, makes a 1d structured array - which its docs describe in some detail.  Since your 2019 link there may have been some changes in structured arrays that makes this `view` approach wrong.  There is a `recfunctions.unstructured_to_ structured` that gets it right, but the result isn't a fast view.  The accepted `isin` answer may be better.

Comment: I don't get your `[(1, 0), (2, 0),...`.  What numpy version?  Is the `pytorch` causing problems?

Comment: Finally, the problem was with dtypes, instead of using 'i,i', I ended up using a records dtype: `base_dtype = src.numpy().dtype; coo_dtype = np.dtype([('src', base_dtype), ('dst', base_dtype)])`. Using `i,i` was using 32 bits integers, while the numbers were 64 bits. Thats why the zero appeared, the number was split in two, and because it was not very big and their most significant bits were just 0.