comparing two lists of tuples, np.isin
I have two lists of tuples and I want to find which elements from the first are in the second one. For example:
elements = [
     (903, 468),
     (913, 468),
     (926, 468),
     (833, 470),
     (903, 470),
     (917, 470),
     (833, 833),
     (903, 833),
     (913, 833),
     (917, 833),
]
    
test_elements = [
    (903, 468), 
    (913, 468), 
    (833, 470), 
    (903, 470), 
    (833, 833), 
    (903, 833),
]

and I want to return a boolean mask for the elements in elements that exist in test_elements. I dont understand why np.isin doesnt give the correct result:
list(map(np.all, np.isin(elements, test_elements)))
>>> [True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False]

which means that (913, 833) should be in test_elements but this is not true
This expesssion however (which I found from another post here) returns the correct mask:
list((np.array(elements)[:,None] == np.array(test_elements)).all(2).any(1))
>>> [True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False]

What am I missing with np.isin (or maybe np.all and map) please?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54850510/1275942 The views answer to that question is quite nice, I think.

np.isin(elements, test_elements) is a 2D array (n rows 2 columns) of booleans saying if a scalar is in test_elements.
Adding a all to each row (which, btw, you should have done with numpy: np.isin(elements, test_elements).all(axis=1), to check if both elements are True, doesn't do what you want. It doesn't check if they are both true because of the same row.
np.isin([(913, 833)], test_elements) is [[True, True]] because both 913 and 833 are in test_elements. So np.isin([(913, 833)], test_elements).all(axis=1) is True, but that doesn't prove what you want.
You cannot achieve what you want with isin. Firstly, rows of elements are not tuple, that can be indexed and compared as in python. They are a bunch of data (numpy hasn't anything like python's tuples). And secondly, anyway, isin documentation says that test_elements is flattened if not 1D. So isin only check for individual scalar values.
If you want to do this with pure numpy (but not sure it is a good idea) you need to do basically an interation (but in numpy).
(np.array(elements)[:,None,:] == np.array(test_elements)[None,:,:])

is a 3D array whose element [x,y,z] says if column z of row x of elements is equal to column z of row y of test_elements
So
(np.array(elements)[:,None,:] == np.array(test_elements)[None,:,:]).all(axis=2)

is a 2D array, whose elemnts [x,y] says if both columns of row x of elements are equal to both columns of row y of test_elements.
So
(np.array(elements)[:,None,:] == np.array(test_elements)[None,:,:]).all(axis=2).any(axis=1)

is a 1D array whose element [x] says if both columns of row x of elemnts are uqual to both columns of any row of test_elements.
Which is what you want.
Again, not sure it is a good idea. Especially starting from python tuples.
If list is small, there is the risk that overheard of translating all that to numpy array is bigger than a pure python search in a set, for example:
S=set(test_elements)
[row in S for row in elements]

(which takes advantage of the fact that tuples are sortable, hashable, comparable, etc, in set structure)
And if list is bigger, then, sure, numpy's overhead becomes negligeable, and the O(n.m.c) algorithm (where n and m are the number of rows of both list, and c the number of columns) will be implemented as fast as possible.
But, still, it is a O(n.m.c) algorithm, while the set version is probably a O(n.log(m)) one. And certainly some ad-hoc method can beat it even if I am naive on set performances. (Like quad-tree, since this is like looking for matching points in a plane)
Either way, it is not really a job for numpy one-liners (you can implement a quadtree library in numpy tho, but that is another story).
tl;dr

isin can't do that
Don't try to do it with a numpy one-liner.
But if you insist on doing it anyway then
(np.array(elements)[:,None,:] == np.array(test_elements)[None,:,:]).all(axis=2).any(axis=1) is the one-liner
If elements is not too big, just use python's set

S=set(test_elements)
[row in S for row in elements]


If those are huge lists, then find an ad-hoc code to search for 2D elements. Like quadtree. Or a dataframe with indexation.


From the docs:

test_elements array_like:
The values against which to test each value of element. This argument is flattened if it is an array or array_like. See notes for behavior with non-array-like parameters.

So your tuples will be flattened, and it'll just check if 913 and 833 are both in np.array(test_elements).flatten(), which they are.

Numpy doesn't preserve the tuples, but rather converts them to arrays and works element-wise, which leads to unexpected results.
A Panda's Series treats things as expected:
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series(elements).isin(test_elements).tolist()
[True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False]

